# Simple full screen image in Android

Tags: android, image

I want to make it such that when a person clicks an image, it opens up in full screen.

What is the most effective way to do this in Android?

The simplest way I can think of is creating an activity, with a layout with the ImageView filling the whole screen. But I think there's some way to directly open just the layout or the ImageView with an Intent?

Comment: Do yo want to open the layout on button click using intent? specify clearly..

Comment: @Raghav Edited for clarity. Doesn't really matter if using intent.

Comment: Mr. Muz, open it Linearlayout or other  with height & width fill_parent.

Comment: I've noticed one way to do this for *online images* is `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(image_url)));`

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to do this is..
When you click on image open a full screen Custom dialog with the image in it having attributes fill parent. You don't need to go in another activity your purpose will be solved in 1 activity itself thereby increasing performance and also lesser activities will be in stack.

Comment: Doesn't work.. dialogs wrap around the content (regardless of whether you use match/fill_parent). And they have an ugly gray area and box around it.

Comment: May be you don"t know how to make a full screen dialog...TRY THIS....Dialog dialog= new Dialog(context,1); dialog.setContentView(your layout); dialog.show();

Comment: Yeah, that's the one I used. The dialog pop up will shrink or distort any images.